# Relaunch application once finished

Tags: shell, command-line, monitoring

Is there a command that relaunch the application once it finishes from the command line? Letting you do something like:

```
> relaunch python myapp.py
```

If not, then what's my best option? I know I could cron it, but I'd be more interested in something I could just execute from the terminal and that restarts at once. I'm on Debian if that matters.

Comment: An important aspect of the question is missing: why is myapp ending in the first place? I ask because often people will think to restart a process that failed because of an error; if so, you can get in a relaunch, fail, repeat loop which waste resources and hides the error.

Comment: @msw - It's exiting because it's done. I added a sleep timer to my version of Eelvex script. :)

Comment: If it is truly "myapp" meaning your code, and it is exiting because it is – as you say – done, then perhaps your definition of "done" needs to be examined in `myapp.py` Crossing levels from Python to shell when you really want the Python app to loop is poor practice, loses state (`exit` gives you one whole integer of return value) and costs at least one process respawn. Worst of all, it can come to bite you in surprising ways 2 months from now.

Comment: And adding sleep to the script only avoids a rapid respawn loop which costs time when things are working and is still broken if `myapp` is failing.

Comment: I was looking for a general solution that was applicable to any executable, of course I could've looped it in the python script itself but I wasn't looking for that, but rather explicitly a command line tool if there was one. I wasn't planning on running anything for 2 months either, just something to use in the moment. I'm well aware of all the issues you've mentioned so far. Can I not shoot myself in the foot if I have a use case for having a hole in my foot?

Comment: fair 'nuff. I like "use case for hole in my foot" I think I shall steal it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with a simple infinite loop:

```
while true; do
  python myapp.py
done
```

*Edit*: the above is just a simple generic example. Most probably modifications are needed to take into account exit errors etc. For example:

```
 until `python myapp.py; echo $?`; do
     echo "exit ok, restarting"
 done
```

Comment: That'll work, but you do run the risk msw pointed out above -- if myapp.py exited because of an error, it'll start up again, crash again, start again, etc in an infinite loop... Potentially locking up your system by hogging CPU time, if the crash happens quickly enough.

Comment: @Shadur: I supposed that the program exits normally since OP says that his application *"finishes"*. Off course, in all other cases you are right.

Comment: @Shadur I realized that too and added a sleep 1 to my version. :)

Comment: @Eelvex There's a [suggested edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/237) you might want to look at

Comment: @Michael: It seems like it is already rejected by someone else. :-/

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry :-\. Well, if you agree with it, just [edit it into your answer manually](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/8590/edit)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop on an error:

```
while [ $? = 0 ]; do
    sleep 1
    python myapp.py
done
echo error: $?
```